# Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/submit?UserName=Admin&Password=super%401234 in Phonegap Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am completely new to Phonegap and Javascript. I am trying to save the username  value and password value from the login form to sqlite database.

This is my login.html file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Login</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action="submit" id="login" name="login_form">
        <input type="text" id="uName" name = "UserName" placeholder="Username" value="Admin"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="password" id="password" name = "Password" placeholder="Password" value="super@1234"/>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Login</button>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            if($("#uName").val()==""){
                alert("Please fill username field.");
                //$("#uName").focus();
            }
            else if($("#password").val()==""){
                alert("Please fill password field.");
                //$("#password").focus();
            }
            else {
                onDeviceReady();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my login.js file:-

```
var db;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
db = window.openDatabase("UserDB", "1.0", "Login", 10000);
db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_err, populateDB_success);
}

function populateDB(tx) {

var userName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (ID INT, USERNAME VARCHAR UNIQUE, PASSWORD VARCHAR)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO users (ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES ("'+1+'","'+userName+'","'+password+'")');
alert("" + userName + " " + password);
}

function transaction_err(tx, error) {
alert("Database Error: " + error);
}

function populateDB_success(tx) {
alert("Data successfully entered.");
window.open("file:///assets/www/view_login.html");
}
```

My problem is when I am running this code in my android device it gives me application error : There is a network error and
error log is:-

```
04-30 10:16:35.080  31868-31868/com.itpp.trt D/CordovaWebViewImpl onPageDidNavigate(file:///android_asset/www/submit?UserName=Admin&Password=super%401234)
04-30 10:16:35.080  31868-31934/com.itpp.trt E/AndroidProtocolHandler﹕ Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/submit?UserName=Admin&Password=super%401234
04-30 10:16:35.090  31868-31868/com.itpp.trt D/SystemWebViewClient﹕ CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-1 Description=There was a network error. URL=file:///android_asset/www/submit?UserName=Admin&Password=super%401234
```

I cant find where is the problem please help me.
Thanks and sorry for the long question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is trying to submit the provided data to the url: 'file:///android_asset/www/submit'.
The url is submitted via the `action` attribute inside the `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="submit" id="login" name="login_form">
```

To prevent this from happening just take the action attribute out of the tag.

Since you are new to Phonegap/Cordova you probably don't know that you shouldn't wait for the `document.ready` event but instead for the `deviceready`. Now when you change this, your form submit will probably no longer work. This is because the `deviceready` event fires once when the App is launched and ready to use. It doesn't wait for a button click or a function declared inside the `deviceready` function.

How can we get this to work again? That's simple, just call a function that when the submit button is clicked. You will need to do something like this:

```
<form id="login" name="login_form" onsubmit="mySubmitFunction();">
```

The called function should look something like this:

```
function mySubmitFunction(){
    $("login").unbind("submit"); //this removes the submit event-handler from the form
    if($("#uName").val()==""){
        alert("Please fill username field.");
    }
    else if($("#password").val()==""){
         alert("Please fill password field.");
    }
    else {
         //insert into your database
         db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_err, populateDB_success);
    }
}
```

Inside the onDeviceReady function just open the database:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
     db = window.openDatabase("UserDB", "1.0", "Login", 10000);
}
```

Comment: Its working now the error is gone, but the transaction_err and populateDB_success are not working. The alert is not showing please help me.

Comment: hmm I just tested it and for me it worked. The alert in populateDB_success popped up.
Have you deleted the ' $(document).ready(function() {...})' ?

Comment: I changed the code to function submitData() {
            onDeviceReady();
            if ($("#uName").val() == "") {
             alert("Please fill username field.")
//$("#uName").focus();
            }
            else if ($("#password").val() == "") {
             alert("Please fill password field.");
//$("#password").focus();
            }
            else {
            alert("its here");
            db.transaction(populateDB, transaction_err, populateDB_success);
            }

            }
abd the its here alert is popped up. but next is not working

Comment: Remove the `onDeviceReady();` . You don't need to call that since you have `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`, it will call the onDeviceReady function when the device is ready.

Comment: I removed the onDeviceReady() so it shows the db variable is undefind.

Comment: Sorry for these silly question. Is it mandatory to call the addEventListener inside head tag?

Comment: It shouldn't matter where it is since jquery runs asynchronously but i would suggest you put it in the head.

Comment: If that doesn't help put the submitData() function in your login.js file

Comment: I tried that still not working, when I call onDeviceReady() then only its workinng. but the database transaction it not working

Comment: Are you testing this in a browser or on a mobile device? It won't work in a browser only on a mobile device with cordova.js

Comment: testing in android device but don't know about cordova.js.

Comment: You are using cordova to build the app right? If so you need to add the cordova.js with the very first `<script>` tag you add to your html

Comment: Now that is working, but its showing this error at every <script>. the error is "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".

Comment: That means that you can't have javascript inside a `<script>` tag so you have to move it into a .js file and load it with a `<script>` tag

Comment: Only populateDB() is working after that it need to show the alert which is  not working.

Comment: Try changing the current db.transaction to this: `db.transaction(function(tx){//put the populateDB code here}, function(tx, error){//put the transaction_err code here}, function(tx){//put the populateDB_success code here});` . I had the same problem once where the callback functions weren't called but I still don't know why.